# PHP array of objects change only a specific items of the object

Tags: php

I am querying from mysql in php but I am in trouble, some of my data is returning in JSON format from MySQL.Here is a picture

[image]

Here price and service timespan is in JSON format but I need to return all things without JSON format.

### Here is my code

```
$response = array();
$query = $wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM ' .self::get_services_table_name() .' LIMIT %d', $limit);
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A );
foreach( $results as $key => $value ){
    $response[$key]->id = $value['id']; 
    $response[$key]->service_name = $value['service_name']; 
    $response[$key]->service_cat_id = $value['service_cat_id']; 
    $response[$key]->service_extra = $value['service_extra']; 
    $response[$key]->price = json_decode($value['price']); 
    $response[$key]->service_timespan = json_decode($value['service_timespan']); 
}
return $response;
```

Inn the array I need only `price` and `service_timespan` to do json_decode. But for this I need to touch all items in the object. How can I get the object changed without touching other params? i.e: `id`, `service_name` etc..

THanks

Comment: You don't need to touch all the other properties, just the ones you want to update.

Comment: What do you mean by __touch__?

Comment: You already do json_decode the values. But i dont think your code runs without error. You should get an error `Creating default object from empty value`. See `$response[$key]->id` and the others. There is no object to set a property.

Comment: BTW; i hope `self::get_services_table_name()` is something static and NOT user input or something you loaded from _somewhere_ . If so then you should prevent SQL-injections by creating a "whitelist" for table names (or if must be dynamically then force to letters (and underscore) only f.e. by using regex `\w`).